# How to get total hours between two datetime fields

Tags: odoo-9

Please let me know how to get total hours between two datetime fields.

This is **.py** file:

```
date_wer=fields.Datetime(string="Date Of Joining")
date_wer1=fields.Datetime(string="Date of Discharge")
```

This is `.xml` file:

```
<field name="date_wer"/>
<field name="date_wer1"/>
```

After this what can I do to get the total hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly subtract two Datetime fields in python.
It will return a timedelta object.

Then you can use the to_seconds method to convert

```
diff=date_wer-date_wer1
diff=diff.to_seconds()
```

this will return a positive/negative value in milliseconds  to diff.